# TextView within a RelativeLayout it is not cropped despite ellipsize

Tags: android

I would like to display a TextView within a RelativeLayout. The text should be cut at the end (`ellipsize`). I set the text in the onCreate method, text is there. Unfortunately the TextView is not displayed to me. If I set `layout_width` to `wrap_content`, the text appears but is not cut off. What is that about?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >


  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userNameTxt"
        android:fontFamily="@font/robotocondensedmedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="33sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"></TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a `RelativeLayout`, `android:layout_width="0dp"` means a width of zero, therefor you can't see any text (`android:layout_width="0dp"` makes sense only in a `ConstraintLayout` and then means `match constraint`). `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` **and** `android:ellipsize="end"` also doesn't make sense (think about: If you give me the freedom to set the width, I never have to cut the text!)